# CMake Couldn't find OPENMP(Mingw,Win10,VSCODE)

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, openmp, mingw32

I'm struggling in compiling a project using OpenMP on Win10. My c++ project is on VSCODE, and I use MINGW32.
The error is :

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:F:.../build
```

The CMakeLists file associated to the search of OpenMP in the project is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(RayTracing)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set (CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH C:/MinGW)

message(STATUS "Checking OpenMP")
find_package(OpenMP)
IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
    message("Found OpenMP! ^_^")
    # add flags for OpenMP
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}  ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    target_link_libraries(RayTracing PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
ELSE()
    message("Missed OpenMP! x_x")
ENDIF()

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(RayTracing ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Yes, I have searched almost all the posts on Internet. But they are all about MacOS and clang. I cannot find a solution for my case. Any ideas? Please, I really need help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still using the old MinGW? You should really use MinGW-w64 instead.

The MinGW-w64 build from http://winlibs.com/ comes with OpenMP.